# Загрузка нескольких изображений на сервер?

Tags: php

Есть такая форма.

```
<input type="file" name="photo_1" size="20" class="file_upload"/>
<input type="file" name="photo_2" size="20" class="file_upload" style="margin-left: 50px;"/>
<br /><br />
<input type="file" name="photo_3" size="20" class="file_upload"/>
<input type="file" name="photo_4" size="20" class="file_upload" style="margin-left: 50px;"/>
```

Возвращает в обработчик `$_FILES`. Как проверить если например 4 изображения нету, его не загружать. Как правильно составить условия? Например, я выбрал 1, 2, 3 изображения, 4 не выбрал. Нажал кнопку загрузить, и загрузились только 1, 2, 3, а 4 не загружалась.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Форма**

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input name="file" type="file" multiple/>
    <input type="button|submit" value="Загрузить" /> 
<!-- Submit - для передачи формы, а Button - для её сериализации с помощью jQuery -->
</form>
```

А кнопкой уже делаете обработку действий. Либо отправляете на скрипт напрямую или обрабатываете с помощью `jQuery`, который передает данные о файлах на скрипт. И там уже проверяете MIME-типы и другую информацию, которую Вам надо.

Answer (score 0):

Может так удобнее будет?

```
<input type="file" name="photo[]" size="20" class="file_upload"/>
<input type="file" name="photo[]" size="20" class="file_upload" style="margin-left: 50px;"/>
<br /><br />
<input type="file" name="photo[]" size="20" class="file_upload"/>
<input type="file" name="photo[]" size="20" class="file_upload" style="margin-left: 50px;"/>
```

Обработчик:

```
print_r($_FILES['photo']);
```